# Assign a vector from another

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector having temperatures in Celsius. How shall I create a new vector which will store converted temperatures(converted using a static formula) in Fahrenheit?

I think there would be a better way than using a loop.

Comment: use [transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11, you can write lambda -

```
std::transform(celVector.begin(),
               celVector.end(),
               std::back_inserter(fahVector),
               [](double c) -> double { return c * 1.8 + 32; });
```

Answer (score 9):

You may use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

```
std::transform(inputVector.begin(), inputVector.end(), std::back_inserter(outputVectot), CToF)
```

where `CToF` is function that convert temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit

Answer (score 1):

You might use std::transform with a std::back_insert_iterator

Answer (score 1):

Most folks are mentioning `std::transform` which is excellent, and Mahesh's answer in particular is great. However, you might also want to note that a C++11 for loop is actually shorter and arguably more readable in this case since you have such a simple transform:

`for (auto c : celVector) fahVector.push_back(c * 1.8 + 32);`